# How to use stored procedure in a sub query to get value in where clause with using main query data as parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, subquery, sql-server-2014

I want to use a stored procedure `GetSLAClass` to get a single value for the where clause as seen in below. And also I want to use `WRMaster` (main table) values as stored procedure parameters. Is there any solution? I want to do both of this works to get correct data.

This is the error msg

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'

Here is my SQL query (currently not working)

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    WRMaster W
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(minute, W.AckedDateTime, W.ResolvedDateTime) <=
        (SELECT Priority
         FROM FMSLAClassPriorityMap
         WHERE SLAClassKey = (EXEC dbo.GetSLAClass W.LocationKey, W.ServicCategoryKey, W.ProblemTypeKey, NULL, ''))
WHERE WRKey=4
```

Comment: yes stored procedures can have return values and both input and output parameters, allowing you to do precisely what you're asking

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible to do, Is there any other solution or method for such tasks?

Comment: yes I suggest you read up on stored procedures

Comment: @WimOmbelets I tryied to execute this query but it show this error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: Not possible, turn it into a function.

Comment: Assume Oracle.  It's 100 per cent possible: as @Dean has said, you need to use a Function to return a value.  This function can have IN parameters but no OUT parameters.  You need to look at your syntax.  **However** there is a performance hit.  The query will need to push every row in WRMaster through the function before it can evaluate the result.  If at all possible avoid using this approach for filtering results

Comment: @dean, This is possible to do with SP , but should use multiple subsidiaries and need to use parameters, This GetSLAClass(SP) returns output parameters

Comment: But as @ChristianPalmer said, there is  a performance hit if I use SP for this task, but can do without funtions, I'm now working on this and sooner I will add answer for this.

Comment: @HasaruDulanShamikara Pls do, I would be very interested in seeing how would you exec a procedure in place of a correlated query in T-SQL.

Comment: @dean, Please check my answer and give me suggestion about performance issues

Answer (score 1):

This is a way that can do this,

```
Declare 
@lk as int,
@sck as int,
@pt as int,
@slaclass as int

select @lk = LocationKey from WRMaster where WRKey=4
select @sck = ServicecategoryKey from WRMaster where WRKey=4
select @pt = ProblemKey from WRMaster where WRKey=4

EXEC   dbo.GetSLAClassOutput @lk,@sck,@pt,NULL,'',  @slaclass output

SELECT *
FROM WRMaster W
WHERE DATEDIFF( minute, W.AckedDateTime, W.ResolvedDateTime )<=
(
  SELECT Priority
  FROM FMSLAClassPriorityMap
  WHERE SLAClassKey=( @slaclass) and PriorityKey = W.PriorityKey
)
where WRKey=4
```

Comment: Use SP with output parameter -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters

Comment: Is there only ever a single row in WRMaster for a particular WRKey value? If this was the case, your performance depends largely on what's inside the stored procedure (there is also an invocation overhead, but let's say it's negligible in this particular case, although it adds up). You can shortcut the initial selects into one, like `select @lk = LocationKey, @sck = ServicecategoryKey, @pt = ProblemKey from WRMaster where WRKey=4`. Anyway, performance-wise, it is always best to inline. Very near to that are inline table UDFs. Everything else is executed on RBAR basis.

Comment: @dean, Thank you for the quires, There is a way that can understand this in different ways, Its my mistake,This answer is only maching for my scenario, I'm passing WRKey.